# Possible for a website link to only be accessed via a specific third party app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, web

I continually provide website links to other companies, they use my website pages within their apps normally via the feature 'webview' however I do not want these pages to be accessed outside of their app.

Is it possible for a website link to only be accessed via a specific third party app without using an API?

I can't seem to find any resolution here except for a HTTP referer but that doesn't seem to be the best method.

Answer (score 0):

You application can do a custom HTTP Request header inside the webview for the web page request and your web-server may able to check for this specific header to return a valid web page

or you might leave the web page blank until the application invoke a specific method to render the web page via WebViews API ( Both iOS and Android allow an application to invoke a javascript from outside the WebViews )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do these have functions have any limitations?  A lot of users within the third party app visit these pages so want to limit any issues or invalid blocking